# android recyclerview setVisibility View.GONE still occupies space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility, cardview

I want to list only the disliked items in my recyclerview. I have a full list of items in rv in MainActivity (did not set visibility here). I can set for each items like or dislike by clicking on imagebutton. The MainActivity shows full list of items (cardviews) that shows imagebutton likes or not. If item is liked, this is stored in firebase db as separate entry under Likes with item key (firebase key .push) and not under Items. (in firebase db I have Users, Items, Likes).

Here is my subactivity code, DislikedItemsActivity, where I want to show only items that are disliked by using setVisibility(View.GONE) for items that are liked. This still holds the space between items for the View.GONE items as well (though these cardviews are empty).

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItemList);
mRecyclerView .setHasFixedSize(true);

final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); 

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, MainActivity.ItemViewHolder> 
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, 
MainActivity.ItemViewHolder>(
            Item.class,
            R.layout.list_item,
            MainActivity.ItemViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MainActivity.ItemViewHolder viewHolder, final Item model, final int position) {

            final String itemKey = getRef(position).getKey();

            mDatabaseItemsLiked.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        // if item is not liked, thus no user set in db ( I want to see only items that are liked in my recyclerview)
                    if (!dataSnapshot.child(itemKey).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                        viewHolder.mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        viewHolder.itemNameSetup(model.getItemName());
                        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                Intent itemSheetIntent = new Intent(DislikedItemsActivity.this, ItemSheetActivity.class);
                                adatlapIntent.putExtra("item_key", itemKey);
                                startActivity(itemSheetIntent);
                            }
                        });

                    } else {

                        viewHolder.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(position); //this puts together the visible items, but when scrolling, it gets messed up

        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, databaseError.toString());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MainActivity.TermekViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            super.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, position);

        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

I looked for many solutions like onBindViewHolder, notifyDataChanged, set margin to 0, set layout size in xml to wrap_content. The best I could get is to have the not-liked items without space with mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(position);, but scrolling the list backwards the whole rv gets messed up (duplicate entry, empty spaces, disordered list).

I don't know how to list only the disliked items from the complete item list from MainActivity rv in a new activity? My code above shows only disliked items, but only until I scroll to end of list, if I scroll backwards the rv gets messed up. I logged the positions of views (18items) in onBindViewHolder and first it counts all items in sequence (17,16,15,14...0), but scrolling from end of list to backwards the position jumps from 0 to 4 like 7times (changes always how many times) then it is the same for item 5,6, until item 17 (all of their positions showed in onBindViewHolder 7 or 8 times during scrolling ie. 5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6) and only for backward scrolling and during backward move rv shows only disliked items or empty views or duplicate entry of disliked item.

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/hatter"
tools:context="com.example.user.itemlist.ItemsLikedActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rvItemList"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

(don't know how to add pics) When disliked list appears, it shows first item (cardview takes up the full screen), and when I start to scroll the list (from 1. visible item to next visible item) if there is space(item1 vis and next vis item is 4), rearrange and I can see that next visible item(item4) moves to 1. visible item, then the rest of the list is arranged well, until I start to scroll back, then it rearranges the rv with spaces and with double entry. The list goes back and forth until both end (which is the length of full items list and not just the disliked items), but visible items gets all messed up.

Comment: show your xml file

Comment: also share screenshot

Comment: You *really* shouldn't be doing the network calls in each row of the RecyclerView. You should download your data in another class and then pass it to the Adapter once it's downloaded. Or filter the list you already have, and then pass that to the adapter. That way you won't need to set the visibility to GONE at all.

Comment: updated with xml and with screenshot description

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your advice -billynomates. How would I know if other users liked or not my items unless I download it from db. I am using firebase's offline capability and the app works offline, so items that are not-liked or changed from like to not-liked appears in the ItemsNotLikedActivity (originally I wrote ItemsLikedActivity, but it is actually ItemsNotLiked). It changes states offline as well. The scrolling is messing up the list.

Comment: I remember that originally I wanted to set the rv list based on the image on each cardview item (look for "like" image), but I don't know how to get reference for each cardview's image if item has "like" image or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution to filter the complete database. In my question I wanted to get only the liked/disliked items in a separate activity, though my previous code showed filtered items, but with gaps.
In below code, I changed the DatabaseReferences (mDatabase -node with complete item list and mDatabaseItemsLiked -node with item uid and user uid).

This gave only empty cards with only number as the likedItems, but to get name from the mDatabase (complete list), I used dataSnapshot.getValue(Item.class).getItemName().

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, 
MainActivity.ItemViewHolder>(
        Item.class,
        R.layout.list_item,
        MainActivity.ItemViewHolder.class,
        mDatabaseItemsLiked

) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final MainActivity.ItemViewHolder
            viewHolder, final Item model, final int position) {

        final String itemKey = getRef(position).getKey();

        mDatabase.child(itemKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
viewHolder.itemNameSetup(dataSnapshot.getValue(Item.class).getItemName());
viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent itemSheetIntent = new Intent(LikedItemsActivity.this, ItemSheetActivity.class);
                            adatlapIntent.putExtra("item_key", itemKey);
                            startActivity(itemSheetIntent);
                        }
                    });
```

This works for me without any problem. I hope it is network efficient.

Answer (score 4):

use this code to remove occupied space :

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 0;
holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the liked ítem in `boolean array` and later in `populateViewHolder` check if ítem has like o no and set visibility.

I would do like that:

1. In your class declare :

> `private boolean [] itemLiked;`

2. In your constructor :

> `this.itemLiked = new boolean [arrayOfAllItems.size]`

3. On click event:

> `itemLiked[position] = true; //Where position is row position`

4. onBindViewholder or in your case populateViewHolder:

   > if (!itemLiked[position])    {
   >   viewHolder.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  }

Hope it helps, good luck!

**EDITED**
I do not understand exactly what you want to do, that's why I leave you the code for two cases.
Case 1. Mark and dis-mark the rows.
Case 2. Save to database or delete.

In continuation the complete code

Activity XML add `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Make a custom layout for row:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_tv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:text="QUESTION"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/like"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/dislike"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>
```

Make a Model class:

```
public class SomeModel {
    private String question;

    public SomeModel(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
}
```

Make Adapter Class:

```
public class SomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private ArrayList<SomeModel> arrayList;
private boolean [] item_has_like, item_hase_vote;

public SomeAdapter(ArrayList<SomeModel> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.item_has_like = new boolean[arrayList.size()];
    this.item_hase_vote = new boolean[arrayList.size()];
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.draw_row, parent, false);
    myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (SomeAdapter.MyViewHolder)holder;
    final SomeModel item = arrayList.get(position);
    int backGround;
   /**In background you can save whateveryou need, example:
    * backGround= R.drawable.some_background;
    * backGround= View.GONE;
    *.....
    **/

    if (item_hase_vote[position]){
        if (item_has_like[position])
        {
            backGround= Color.GREEN;// 
        } else {
            backGround= Color.RED;
        }
    } else {
        backGround= Color.TRANSPARENT;
    }
    myViewHolder.questionTV.setText(item.getQuestion());
    myViewHolder.questionTV.setBackgroundColor(backGround);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView questionTV;
    private ImageView like, dislike;

    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        questionTV = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_tv);
        like = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
        dislike = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dislike);

        like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Item  been voted
                item_hase_vote[getAdapterPosition()] = true;
                //Item got Like save in boolean array by row position
                item_has_like[getAdapterPosition()] = true;
                //notify your adapter
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                /*OR Here comes the code where You save Item in Your Data Base.*/
            }
        });
        dislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Item  been voted
                item_hase_vote[getAdapterPosition()] = true;
                // Item got DisLike save in boolean array by row position
                item_has_like[getAdapterPosition()] = false;
                //notify your adapter
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                /*OR Here You Remove item on Dislike
                arrayList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(),arrayList.size());
                */
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

And Your Activity:

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_some);

    ArrayList<SomeModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <77 ; i++) {
        arrayList.add(new SomeModel("Question " + i));
    }
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_rv);
    SomeAdapter adapter = new SomeAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

}
```

}

Saving the selected item by the adapterPosition in boolean, String, int....[], the Adapter always gona know whats going on with every item and like that your list always gona be arranged.

Good Luck!

Comment: I got same result with your solution. The view.gone set it invisible only, the spaces are still there. I noticed now that doing only setvisibility does not remove the space. When I put notifyItemRemoved(position) in populateViewHolder, else side

Comment: The view.gone sets items invisible only, the spaces are still there. I noticed now that doing only setvisibility does not remove the space. When I put notifyItemRemoved(position) in populateViewHolder in the else side, then the rv sets only the visible items only (ie. out of 18 items only 5 that are not-liked are visible) without space, but after scrolling until end of list (5 items) the scrolling stops I can go only backward and this is when all gets messed up and I can scroll back now 18 items (some are invisible or duplicate entry).

Comment: I couldn't edit my prev. comment. 
I don't know how to put in my Item class the construtor you recommended. I don't know how to get the arrayOfAllItems.size there. 
I made the changes in ItemsNotLikeActivity.class. I put your constructor in the populateViewHolder, and put the on click on the else side.

Comment: @Zeghra check my answer again, Hope it will be usefull for you!

Comment: Your idea to save position in array list and set visible these sounds really good. What I want to do is that have only dislike items in rv with cardviews that have name and imagebutton(default state dislike). If this imagebutton is pressed, the image changes to like. Have a rv that shows all items, and have another rv (how?) in another activity that shows disliked items only. 
If imagebutton is pressed on dislikeActivity (that shows only disliked items), this item should be gone as well (since this became liked). Preferably only filtering rv and not downloading query from db through network.

Comment: ph7 - it seems to me that your advice is more about how to reference like and dislike items, which I've got. In MainActivity, I have complete list that shows if item is liked or disliked. I don't know how to narrow rv from complete list to only dislike list in DislikeItemsActivity. I cannot get position of items before it starts adapter and my adapter in DislikeItemsActivity uses the MainActivity's viewholder, which is the complete list. I just set for this complete list in DislikeItemsActivity that if itemKey has no Like in db then create the item's view, else view.gone.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem. what i thought was if `RelativeLayout` load one after one, height=0, the specs will remove.So it works for me.

**This is my ViewHolder. I Introduces my reletivelayout here.**

```
   public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            View mView;
            TextView txtdate;
            RelativeLayout con_rel;
            String name_day = "no name";

            public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mView=itemView;
                con_rel=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.con_rel);
                txtdate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.day);
            }
    }
```

The I set **height** and **width**

```
    con_ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/consultation");
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Consultation,SelectConsaltation.BlogViewHolder>recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter< Consultation,SelectConsaltation.BlogViewHolder>(
                    Consultation.class,
                    R.layout.consultation_card,
                    SelectConsaltation.BlogViewHolder.class,
                    con_ref
            ) {
     @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final SelectConsaltation.BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Consultation model, final int Consultation) {

                    Shedule_ref.child(model.getScheduleID()).child("Day").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                       ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewHolder.con_rel.getLayoutParams();
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            name_day = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                            if (doctor_id_from_doctor.equals( model.getDoctorID() )){

                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                Date strDate = null;

                                try {
                                    strDate = sdf.parse(model.getDate());
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                if(System.currentTimeMillis()<=strDate.getTime() ) {
                                    params.height = 300;
                                    params.width =800;
                                    viewHolder.con_rel.setLayoutParams(params);
                                    viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate(),name_day);
                                }
                                else {

                                    **params.height = 0;
                                    params.width = 0;
                                    viewHolder.con_rel.setLayoutParams(params);**
                                }

                               }
                            else {
                                params.height = 0;
                                params.width = 0;
                                viewHolder.con_rel.setLayoutParams(params);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });


                }
            };
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


        }
```

**My card view code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/con_rel"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#a2ffffff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_07th_of_sunday_january_2018_at_9_00am"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextnumber"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colornextnumber"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/next_avealable_number_is_04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/booknow"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorbookNow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/book_now"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my inreface[image]